# OpenCV build undefined reference to protobuf built from source

Tags: opencv, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build OpenCV from source. I have protobuf installed to my home directory; it was built with `--enable-shared`. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has `$HOME/lib` at the head; `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` are set to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `CPATH` is set to `$HOME/include`. `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is to `$HOME/lib/pkgconfig`.

Here are some relevant versions:

```
opencv==3.1.0
gcc==4.8.5
g++==4.8.5
python==3.5.2
protobuf==2.6.1
```

My CMake command is

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$HOME/opencv_contrib-3.1.0/modules -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=$HOME/bin/python -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME ..
```

cmake succeeds and even says that it found PROTOBUF at `<~>/lib/libprotobuf.so`. But make fails to find it.

```
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteStringMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream::WriteStringWithSizeToArray(std::string const&, unsigned char*)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::InitEmptyString()'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_once_init_'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteBytesMaybeAliased(int, std::string const&, google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream*)'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
../../lib/libopencv_dnn.so.3.1.0: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream::BytesUntilTotalBytesLimit() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_dnn] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_dnn.dir/all] Error 2
```

A couple of other places mention that multiple versions of protobuf can cause problems. There *is* another protobuf in /lib64, but I can't remove it since I don't have root access. So I'm not sure what the workaround is.

Comment: I'm striking the same problem with GCC 4.8.5 or 4.9, but openCV builds ok with gcc 5.4. Unfortunately I need to build with an earlier GCC as Matlab doesn't yet officially support GCC 5

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue recently because I installed the latest protobuf (3.1.0) and built my opencv with GCC 4.9. When I switched back to GCC 5, OpenCV 3.1 can be built successfully.

If you want to use Matlab together with OpenCV 3.1 I think you may need to downgrade your protobuf version, like protobuf-2.5.0, then you can use GCC 4.9 to rebuilt the OpenCV.